# Compare Employee Names To Master List

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I am comparing a list of employees to a master list, and getting a count.  This works as it should, but now I need to add a caveat to ignore certain employee names (like `Manager, Supervisor, Mgr, Sup`) from the counts.

The list received has location in column A and the names in column C - so I would need to ignore the names in the array above that would exist in Column C from the counts.

...
This is what I am using to return the count -> how can it be modified to ignore the array of names listed above?

```
Const shLookup As String = "Master List"
Const shSetup As String = "Received"

With Worksheets(shLookup)
aData = .Range("a1").CurrentRegion
End With
ReDim aOutput(1 To UBound(aData), 1 To 3)
For i = 2 To UBound(aData)
iCount = Evaluate("=COUNTIF('" & shSetup & "'!A:A,'" & shLookup & "'!A" & i & ")")
If aData(i, 2) <> iCount Then
    n = n + 1
    aOutput(n, 1) = aData(i, 1)
    aOutput(n, 2) = aData(i, 2)
    aOutput(n, 3) = iCount
End If
Next
```

**EDIT**
Sample worksheet data would look like this:

```
Master List sheet
Store   EmpCount
Memphis  23
Houston  13
Phili    10


Received List Sheet
Store   Region   EmpName
Memphis East     Joe
Memphis East     James
Memphis East     Jane
Memphis East     Supervisor
Memphis East     Manager
```

What I am after is to ensure that on the received list sheet there are 23 employees for Memphis, **excluding** the names above from the count.

**EDIT 2**
Per the suggestion in comments by @PKatona - it looks like I can use the `CountIF()` function to count the "ignore" values then subtract that count from my whole count.  This syntax seems to work for one by one, however, how would I adapt it for an array?

I.E. this would give me the count for `Manager` but there are other buzz words I need to search for:

```
iIgnore = Evaluate("=COUNTIF(Range('" & shSetup & "'!A:A,'" & shLookup & "'!A" & i & "),"Manager")")
```

Comment: Could you give us a sample table of your columns?

Comment: @CLR - updated to show sample data.

Comment: How about adding "CountIf" commands to count the values you don't want and then subtract that from the iCount? Something like iCount = iCount - Evaluate(CountIf(...)).

Comment: @PKatona - not sure how to implement that into my syntax.  Example?

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head without syntax checking, here's how you'd create the array of ignore values and then count them:

```
dim ignore() as String
ignore = Split("Manager,Supervisor,Mgr,Sup", ",")
dim ignoreCnt as integer
ignoreCnt = 0
dim aIdx as integer

for aIdx = 0 to UBound(ignore) - 1
    ignoreCnt = ignoreCnt + Evaluate("=COUNTIF(Range('" & shSetup & _
          "'!A:A,'" & shLookup & "'!A" & i & "),ignore(aIdx))")
next aIdx
```

ignoreCnt now has the total of the values you want to ignore. If you have more, just add them to the string in the Split line, the UBound function automatically gets the upper limit for the loop.